# Issues with Database.upsert statement

Tags: apex, dml

I am using a Database.upsert statement to upsert a custom object record in apex. In my method, i do an upsert and i am printing the id and the errors. I am getting an id on the result and also the error message is showing up as blank. But I dont see the record in the  database if i do a query or even if i go to the custom object tab view. Has any one encountered issues like this?

```
public static void upsertRecord(SObject record){
        Database.UpsertResult sr = Database.upsert(record,false);
        String errMessage = '';
        // Check the Save Result
        if(!sr.isSuccess()){
            Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
            errMessage = err.getMessage();
        }

        System.debug('upsert Record dml operation'+sr.getId() + 'errmsge'+errMessage);
```

In the above record, my getid returns an id and errmessage is null.Has anyone faced a situation where salesforce would return an id but still not populate any record?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: What happens if you paste the Id value in the URL Address bar, i.e xx.salesforce.com/ID - if you get insufficient privileges it could be to do with sharing.

Comment: @techtrekker I pasted the id on the url address bar and the page does not show the record at all. I did a query in soql and still i could not find the record in db. Anybody had such weird issues.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but are you sure you're checking in the right org. What did you get when you hit the url ? Data not found or insufficient privileges ?

Comment: Anything further in the code flow that might rollback whole transaction? Fatal error? Governor limit being hit? Savepoint rollback? @future method that sends them straight to recycle bin (ridiculous, I know ;)) Are you sure that THIS method gets called (for example if you have a similar one that accepts `Account record` - if it'll be a better match for the compiler...

Comment: The apex code could be running in the system context where as the current user doesn't have sufficient access to see the record. Maybe give your user profile the "view all data" permission.

Comment: how are you actually running this code ?

Answer (score 4):

You've posted your code below. I see a couple of issues with it that would seem to explain your problem.

```
    String errMessage = ''; // you've defined this as a zero length string
    if(!sr.isSuccess()){
        // The line below is the one that actually captures your 1st error    
        Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0]; 
        errMessage = err.getMessage(); // <--- This captures nothing
        errMessage = sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage(); // This captures actual error mssg
    }

    System.debug('upsert Record dml operation'+ sr.getId() + 'errmsge'+ errMessage);
```

Your code wasn't getting the error message as the reference to the save results had already been lost when it was saved to the variable named "err" which was presumably being used to capture the error code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his code from what I can see. Assigning `''` to `errMessage` is not a problem, later on the variable is just assigned a new string, this is standard practice.

Also assinging the first entry in the array to `err` just means there are now two references to the same object, one in the first array slot and `err` itself. There is no difference between the two ways of calling `getMessage()`.

Comment: @LaceySnr. I've never seen getMessage() called in the above manner. It might behoove the OP to add a `System.debug` line below 'errMessage = err.getMessage();` in his code to see if its capturing anything as he's written it. The only point I was making with respect to errMessage being initialized as `= ''` is that's the value its returning when another string value is expected.